# Jquery Bread Crumb

Tags: jquery, html, breadcrumbs

I'm following this tutorial on creating a bread crumb trail for my webpages. The links, when clicked in the **bread crumb trail** goes to it's respective page. But the same links, when clicked from the **navigation section** does not work (stays on the same page) -please see URLs test1.html and test2.html-.

Here is the script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.items a').on('click', function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                $bc = $('<div class="item"></div>');

            $this.parents('li').each(function (n, li) {
                var $a = $(li).children('a').clone();
                $bc.prepend(' / ', $a);
            });
            $('.breadcrumb').html($bc.prepend('<a href="#home">Home</a>'));
            return false;
        })
    </script>
```

...here is the HTML / Navigation links:

```
  <div class="breadcrumb">
        <div class="item"><a href="index.html">Home / </a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="items">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="test1.html">Test 1</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="test2.html">Test 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="level1">Level 1</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="level2">Level 2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="level3">Level 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="level4">Level 4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#test1">Test 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

...the links in the bread crumb goes to it's respective page when clicked; the problem is, the same links, when clicked in the navigation section does not work. Could I get some help as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you show the html generated by the script, the breadcrumbs html

Comment: this is the URL to the script and hypertext: https://codepen.io/kennethhu/pen/Woryzg